# JSON to POJO using GSON. Help required modelling the data

Tags: java, json, gson

I have provided a cut down JSON object that I am trying to convert into a Java POJO. I have renamed the name / value pairs to keep it simple.

```
{
    "content": {
        "name1": "value1",
        "name2": [
            [
                ["string1", "string2", 1],
                ["string3", "string4", 2]
            ],
            [
                ["string5", "string6", 3],
                ["string7", "string8", 4]
            ]
        ],
        "name3": "value3"
    }
}
```

Previously I have used the GSON “fromJson” to convert similar objects. Struggling to work out the correct class representation of this and would appreciate if someone could help me out. The issue I have is with the JSON name value pair “name2”. (name2 can have 1 or more JSON arrays within it).

I have tried representing this as follows however this does not work correctly.

```
public class Content {
public String name1;
public Name2 name2;
public String name3;
}
public class Name2 {
public List <Name2Data> = new ArrayList <>();
}

public class Name2Data {
    public String value1;
    public String value2;
    public Integer integer1;
}
```

Any help how to model this correctly or advice if there is a better approach would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name2` is not a `Name2` object. It is an array of array of array of strings or integers. You can't really simply model it like that, you'd need a custom deserializer.

Comment: for `["string1", "string2", integer1]` I'd use a JSON object instead of an array, if possible.

Comment: I have validated your JSON for you since `integer1` is not an actual number

Comment: Thank you all for the help, appreciated. The JSON is from a third party provider so I had no way of changing it so DwB's answer helped me most. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Editorial

The JSON design is terrible.

### Answer

Here are some classes

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(
        String[] args)
    {
        DataObject dataObject;
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        final String nuttyJson = "{\"content\": { \"name1\": \"value1\", \"name2\": [ [ [\"string1\", \"string2\", 1], [\"string3\", \"string4\", 2] ], [ [\"string5\", \"string6\", 3], [\"string7\", \"string8\", 4] ] ], \"name3\": \"value3\" } }";

        dataObject = gson.fromJson(nuttyJson, DataObject.class);

        dataObject = null;
    }
}
```

**DataObject.java**

```
public class DataObject
{
    private Content content;

    private class Content
    {
        private String name1;
        private Object[][][] name2;
        private String name3;

        public String getName1()
        {
            return name1;
        }

        public Object[][][] getName2()
        {
            return name2;
        }

        public String getName3()
        {
            return name3;
        }

        public void setName1(
            final String newValue)
        {
            name1 = newValue;
        }

        public void setName2(
            final Object[][][] newValue)
        {
            name2 = newValue;
        }

        public void setName3(
            final String newValue)
        {
            name3 = newValue;
        }
    }

    public Content getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }


    public void setContent(
        Content content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this it was driving me mad. Unfortunately I am just a consumer of this JSON data so I have no way of changing the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

name2 of the JSON example, is an array that contains arrays which in turn contain arrays.

```
List<List<List>> name2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

would probably work. A list of lists, that contain lists that contain values of multiple types.

Correct me if I'm wrong. This gets confusing really fast. Also I cannot test this at the moment.

If you were to use a JSON object instead of that inner most array you could use

```
List<List<InnerData>> name2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

where `InnerData` is a model that would fit the object version of
`["string1", "string2", 1]` e.g.:

```
{
    "string1": "string1",
    "string2": "string2",
    "anInt": 1
}
```